# C# static class (for global config), update from other class

Tags: c#, .net

I use a public static class to specify some global values which I need to use some times in multiples classes.

```
public static class GlobalConfig
{
        public static Int32 lm1 = 2000;
        public static Int32 lm2 = 5;
}
```

I later on use it in different classes like :

```
GlobalConfig.lm2
```

What would be the solution to also be able to update this value from outside the class itself / from an other class ?

Comment: Convert the fields to static properties:
`public static Int32 lm1 { get; set; }`
And initialize them in a static constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update these values directly.

```
GlobalConfig.lm1 = 2001;
```

Or if you want to be able to add new global values as and when, use a dictionary.

```
public static class GlobalConfig
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Int32> Settings = new Dictionary<string, int32>();
}
```

Then add settings using:

```
GlobalConfig.Settings.Add("lm1", 2000);
```

And get using.

```
var setting = GlobalConfig.Settings["lm1"];
```